# Merge and autocrop images with Jimp

Tags: javascript, image, typescript, processing

The following code uses [jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) to merge images, located in the `./in` folder, with `dots.png`. Then it autocrops the images. Finally, they are written into the `./out` folder.

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as path from 'path'
import jimp from 'jimp'

(async () => {
  const filenames = fs.readdirSync('./in').map(filename => {
    return path.parse(filename).name
  })

  const finalImages = await Promise.all(filenames.map(async filename => {
    const bottomImage = await jimp.read(`./in/${filename}.png`)
    const topImage = await jimp.read('./dots.png')

    console.log(`Manipulating: ${filename}`)
    const file = bottomImage
      .composite(topImage, 0, 0)
      .autocrop(false)
    console.log(`Finished manipulating: ${filename}`)
    return { filename, file }
  }))

  interface finalImage {
    file: jimp
    filename: string
  }

  finalImages.forEach((finalImage: finalImage) => {
    console.log(`Writing: ${finalImage.filename}`)
    finalImage.file.write(`./out/${finalImage.filename}.png`)
    console.log(`Finished writing: ${finalImage.filename}`)
  })
})()
```

There's a problem: when this code processes more than 10 images, the computer hangs/freezes (at least in mine).

So I think somewhere in this code too much is going on at the same time. Could it be the code inside `Promise.all`? Where `jimp` is manipulating too many images at the same time?

How to modify this code so the computer doesn't hang/freezes with more than 10 images (e.g. 20)?